# How to deal with white space in DataFrame name, pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, namespaces

I created a `Data Frame` with the name **'df_new dataframe'** when I was looping using the **`globals()`** option. 
How to print or display the `Data Frame` when it has white spaces in its name?

Comment: How did you create a dataframe with a space?!

Comment: You have to access it via `globals()['df_new dataframe']`...

Comment: wow! it would be interesting to know how did you manage to create a variable containing space in its name...

Comment: @MaxU do `globals()['2 +2'] = 'test'` and then you've got a name that's not a valid name literal but an actual expression... then look at what `dir()` shows you

Comment: @JonClements, thank you for the hint! Why would people want to do that? ;-)

Comment: @MaxU *shrugs*...

Comment: *I was looping using the globals() option* ... reconsider this approach as `globals()` should rarely if not ever be used.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that is one way I would use. I was expecting if there is something different that I could try. Please let me know if there is any, thank you

Comment: @MaxU Is there any other way that different dataframes could be built using loop?

Comment: @ClemV, there are many different ways... What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: for i in list:
     globals()['df_%s'%i]=df[df['col']==i]
how would you create this?